# Google calendar export application error

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am writing a short application for exporting events to Google calendar. (Events are obtained from code processing information from my website.) However, when I click the button, the script I wrote is giving me a strange error. The error I get the first time I click the button is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setApiKey' of undefined`. However, the second time I click the button without refreshing the page, the error disappears and the code runs perfectly.

Here is my code, as you can see I defined the api key before setting it:

```
var exportCalendarToGoogle = function() {
    var clientId = '38247913478902437.google@user...';
    var scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
    var apiKey = 'JDKLSFDIOP109321403AJSL';

    var withGApi = function() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        gapi.auth.init(checkAuth);
      }
    var checkAuth = function() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scope, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
    }

    var handleAuthResult = function(authResult) {
        if(authResult) {
            gapi.client.load("calendar", "v3", exportCalendar);
        } else {
            alert("Authentication failed: please enter correct login information.");
        }
    }
 //functions to format the calendar json input to Google calendar...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `gapi` has not been fully loaded

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/GettingStarted

There are two callbacks:

1) In the URL to load the gapi code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

2) You can also supply a callback function that will let you know when a specific API has loaded:

`gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() { console.log('loaded.'); });`

I think your problem is 1)